# How to convert psd file to html template?

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

I have a psd files of my website design, So can i convert it into html template.

Template should contain html,css code.

Basically i am beginner in photoshop so i don't know, it will possible or not.

Please help.

Comment: there is no magic wand , you have to write code for that. psd is all about getting help in colors , graphics, design, orientation, typography and all that stuff.

Comment: This question should be close as its just spam on site and not useful for any other user.

Answer (score 0):

Well the good part is that you have the static design, what means that there is no interaction with a user, of your website ready.

I would suggest you to start with one or another interactive prototyping tool like [Marvel](https://marvelapp.com/). Then you can prototype the functionalities of the website and start working on code writing part. This step will also help you and people, who are going to help you, to get the idea what you want to achieve as a final result.

There are also Adobe solutions like [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) what gives you an option to migrate the Photoshop layers to webpage. But this solution is not free.

After you finish working with prototyping you can take a really good free course on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-html-and-css--ud304) about developing solutions with HTML5 and CSS3. [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/skills/make-an-interactive-website) also has good set of courses on this topic.

Hope this helps to start your journey in learning PSD to HTML techniques and web development in general.